# Creating an integer to use with param type integer in ColdFusion

Tags: parameters, coldfusion, type-conversion

I'm a fan of using required arguments with types where appropriate. I want to write a function which requires an integer as an argument and errors if it is passed anything else. Generally I have been using `required numeric num` however `numeric` will accept floats and doubles etc. I understand from the [adobe cfparam docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7faf.html) (although I much prefer the [cfdocs version](https://cfdocs.org/cfparam)) that `integer` is a valid parameter type.

What I don't understand is how to create an integer in the first place. I gather CF does some things under the hood storing numbers as strings but as you can see from the cfscript below, I've tried a few different things, and got their types from `getMetaData()` and none of them are actually integers.

To add to my confusion, many of these types return `true` from `isValid("integer", num)` whilst still failing `required integer num`.

Most grateful if you can point me in the right direction.

```
private void function printMeta( required num ){
    writeOutput( '</br>' );
    writeOutput( ARGUMENTS.num );
    writeOutput( '</br>' );
    writeOutput( getMetaData( ARGUMENTS.num ).getName() );
    writeOutput( '</br>' );
    writeOutput( 'isValid integer? ' & isValid( 'integer', ARGUMENTS.num ) );
    writeOutput( '</br>' );
}

private numeric function addOne( required numeric num ){
    return ARGUMENTS.num + 1;
}


private function needsInt( required integer num ){
    return "what a lovely integer you've got there, it's " & ARGUMENTS.num;
}


test1 = 2;
printMeta( test1 );


test2 = addOne( test1 );
printMeta( test2 );

test3 = Int( 7 );
printMeta( test3 );

test4 = numberFormat( 8 );
printMeta( test4 );

try {
    test5 = needsInt( Int( 7 ) );
}
catch(any err) {
    WriteOutput('<br />');
    WriteDump( err.message );
    WriteOutput('<br />');
}

try {
    test6 = needsInt( test2 );
}
catch(any err) {
    WriteOutput('<br />');
    WriteDump( err.message );
    WriteOutput('<br />');
}

test7 = 3.5;
printMeta( test7 );

test8 = addOne( test7 );
printMeta( test8 );
```

Outputs:

2
java.lang.String
isValid integer? YES

3
java.lang.Double
isValid integer? YES

7
java.lang.Long
isValid integer? YES

8
java.lang.String
isValid integer? YES

The NUM argument passed to the needsInt function is not of type integer.

The NUM argument passed to the needsInt function is not of type integer.

3.5
java.lang.String
isValid integer? NO

4.5
java.lang.Double
isValid integer? NO

The NUM argument passed to the needsInt function is not of type integer.

**Edit** I tried specifically creating a java integer and still didn't manage to get it to work;

```
test11 = createObject("java","java.lang.Integer").parseInt("5");
printMeta( test11 );

    try {
    test12 = needsInt( test11 );
}
catch( any err ) {
    WriteOutput('<br />');
    WriteDump( err.message );
    WriteOutput('<br />');
}
```

Ouputs:

5
java.lang.Integer
isValid integer? YES

The NUM argument passed to the needsInt function is not of type integer.

Comment: This article explains how the isValid function is really just checking against MySQL types, so it looks like it's saying it's a valid mysql integer, not CF: http://eclectic-thoughts.com/my-web-developer-life/

Comment: Try creating the integer  using Java's create object, again show in the bottom of that article `#createObject("java","java.lang.Integer").parseInt("987654321987)#`

Comment: thanks @wilshawMedia, I've updated my question with your suggestion and did manage to create an actual integer! ..but still not got it to pass parameter validation. Which seems even more weird!

Comment: I've written a script to test & compare various built-in functions & UDFs that evaluate integers. https://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/155123452479/coldfusion-validation-of-numbers-wextra-hidden A custom UDF is recommended.

Comment: @JamesMoberg Nice, I'll look in to that in more detail later. Liked your use of `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` which I must remember to use more :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't actually know what your precise question is, but I think your *problem* is that there is no native argument type `integer` in CFML. It's just `numeric`. This will take any value than can be coerced into a numeric value: strings containing only digits, booleans, dates, stuff like that).

If you have this:

```
function f(required integer x)
```

Then CFML will interpret that as being of type integer.cfc. Not "an integer" in the comp-sci sense, nor a Java int primitive, or a java.lang.Integer etc.

If you need your argument to be an actual integer, then use `numeric`, then validate it as an integer within the function body, eg:

```
function f(required numeric x) {
    param integer x;
    // ...
}
```

Ugly, but does the trick.

[Here's an example on trycf.com](https://trycf.com/gist/ddc2104bcf0e95093497b3e57756bda4/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: You're right, I got confused between parameters and arguments. I should have been looking at the docs for cfargument ([Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-a-b/cfargument.html), [cfdocs](https://cfdocs.org/cfargument)).

Comment: That's super obvious now you point it out, integer in this case is a custom CFC. It is weird though that cfparam accepts integer as a valid type, seems like a bit of a red herring

Comment: @adamcameron That example combining and argument and a parameter is interesting and useful, thanks. The whole thing is weird, but that is helpful...

Comment: @WillshawMedia It's the little inconsistencies like `cfparam` and `cfargument` allowing different data type validations that make us love CF so much. #smh